# SHA512 hashing with secret key

Tags: java, security

What is the Java equivalent of http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php ?

I need to specify both the data and the secret key to generate a SHA512 hash.

Best I've found so far is http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha512Hex(java.lang.String) 
but how do I specify the key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an SHA512 digest string in Java using bouncy castle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208374/how-can-i-create-an-sha512-digest-string-in-java-using-bouncy-castle)

Comment: I need to specify the `key` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) and especially its [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

For instance like this:

```
public String calcSha(String secret, String data) {
    return DigestUtils.sha512Hex(secret + data);
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer. The PHP-version is probably doing similar thing inside.

Comment: I don't get it- you pass the secret with the data as a concatenated string? Why aren't they two separate parameters?

Comment: This is incorrect, HMAC (per the original question) would be `H(secret XOR outer-padding, H(secret XOR inner-padding, data))` ([RFC 2104](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104)), not just a naive concatenation of a secret and a message. This is to [resist length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). Also, do not use `String` types everywhere at such a low level, prefer to encode/decode for armoring at the boundaries, and only if necessary. @IcedDante: That's because this isn't a HMAC, a normal hash function has only one parameter and no notion of secret keys.

Answer (score 2):

Bouncy Castle includes an [HMAC class](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/index.html) which can use any digest (=hash) available, including SHA-256.